# How do I wire a 24VAC transformer where the primary and secondary exit through the same conduit connector?

Tags: electrical

I'd like to use a Class 2 24VAC 75VA transformer ([Resideo AT175F](https://customer.resideo.com/resources/Techlit/TechLitDocuments/68-0000s/68-0054.pdf)). Both the primary and secondary wires exit through the same conduit connector:

[image: transformer diagram]

However, NEC 725.136(A) states that I can't place cables and conductors of Class 2 and Class 3 circuits (secondary wires) in the same device box with power conductors (primary wires).

I'm having a difficult time understanding it, but it seems like 725.136(D)(2)(a) might give me an out?

```
The Class 2 and Class 3 circuits are installed using Type CL3, CL3R, or CL3P or permitted substitute cables, provided these Class 3 cable conductors extending beyond the jacket  are separated by a minimum of 6 mm (0.25 in.) or by a nonconductive sleeve or nonconductive barrier from all other conductors.
```

725.136(D) talks about when the associated systems are within enclosures
725.136(D)(2) further specifies that the circuit conductors operate at 150 volts or less (true in my case)

So does that mean I can connect one of these transformers to the exterior of an enclosure (via a 7/8" knockout), run all the wires (primary and secondary) inside and make my connections with something like a [terminal block](https://www.gardnerbender.com/en/p/GTB-406/6-Pole-Terminal-Block#)? Do I even need a terminal block? Can I just use wire nuts with both circuit types inside the enclosure?

[image: terminal block]

Comment: Wrong transfromer for that application.  They make quite a lot of 24V transformers that mount on a KO like that, or j-box lid, and expose the two 24V terminals outside. I thought I saw one like that in that same spec sheet.  Anyway, yeah, that one is for when the 24V control wiring will remain inside Class 1 wiring.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, thanks! Mind adding your comment as an answer? I'm also a little fuzzy on what Class 1 wiring means in this case (it's a Class 2 transformer).

Comment: What are you trying to run/power with this transformer?

Comment: @ThreePhase, I'm powering some 24VAC LED landscape lighting.

Comment: What sort of cable are you running from the transformer to the lights themselves?

Comment: Direct burial irrigation wire. Not ideal, but it's what's in the ground. Sometimes I have to use several 18 gauge conductors per light to make sure the voltage drop isn't too significant.